# Jquery password strength checker code improvment

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, passwords

I've done a part of this code to change the color of the progress bar regarding it's value.
It goes from red to green regarding the password strength.
I think there is a way better methods to have it done. However it works perfectly.
Can someone check it to see if there is a cleaner way to acheive it please?

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var pass = document.getElementById("password")
    pass.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        checkPassword(pass.value)
    })
    function checkPassword(password) {
        var strengthBar = document.getElementById("strength")
        var strength = 0;
        if (password.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+/)) {
            strength += 1
        }
        if (password.match(/[~<>?]+/)) {
            strength += 1
        }
        if (password.match(/[!@£$%^&*()]+/)) {
            strength += 1
        }
        if (password.length > 5) {
            strength += 1
        }
        if (password.length > 8) {
            strength += 1
        }
        switch(strength) {
            case 0:
                strengthBar.value = 0
                $('#strength').removeClass('red')
                break
            case 1:
                strengthBar.value = 20
                $('#strength').addClass('red')
                $('#strength').removeClass("orange")
                break
            case 2:
                strengthBar.value = 40
                $('#strength').removeClass("red")
                $('#strength').addClass('orange')
                $('#strength').removeClass("yellow")
                break
            case 3:
                strengthBar.value = 60
                break
            case 4:
                strengthBar.value = 80
                $('#strength').removeClass("orange")
                $('#strength').addClass('yellow')
                $('#strength').removeClass("green")
                break
            case 5:
                strengthBar.value = 100
                $('#strength').removeClass("yellow")
                $('#strength').addClass('green')
                break
        }
    }
```

HTML code for testing purpose:

```
<h1>Progress</h1>
<label>Enter password</label>
<input style="width: 200px" type="text" autocomplete="none" id="password">
<progress id="strength" class="strength" value="0" max="100"> 32% </progress>
```

CSS that goes with:

```
progress.strength {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
progress.strength::-webkit-progress-value {
    background;
}
progress.red::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:red;
}
progress.orange::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:rgb(255, 153, 0);
}
progress.yellow::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:rgb(229, 255, 0);
}
progress.green::-webkit-progress-value {
    background:rgb(53, 252, 13);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of regular expressions to test against, and clean them up by using the case-insensitive flag and `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. From there, you can determine the total strenth by iterating over the array and testing each.

Instead of assigning the `.value` for each possibility, multiply the `strength` by 20. Eg `2 * 20` results in `40`.

Use an array of classes corresponding to each strength value. Overwrite the prior classes completely in advance instead of trying to figure out the previous color.

```
const colors = ['', 'red', 'orange', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'];
const patterns = [
     /[a-z\d][a-z\d]{2,}/i,
     /[~<>?]+/,
     /[!@£$%^&*()]+/,
     /.{6}/,
     /.{9}/,
];
const strength = patterns.reduce((count, pattern) => count + pattern.test(password), 0);
strengthBar.value = strength * 20;
$('#strength')
  .removeClass(colors.join(' '))
  .addClass(colors[strength]);
```

Comment: You've wonderfully cleaned the code! And it does works like a charm thanks.
I've seen in the next post a function to diseable the submit button in case of weak password. Is there's a way to implement it too? I've tried with an added css class but it doesn't work nice.

Comment: Something like `$('.submit').prop('disabled', strength <= 1)`

Comment: It can do the job with a small modification I think. I've tried it but it leave the button activated if nothing is entered in the input. Then at the first password state it was disabled and then it was enabled again. I've tried to add "disable" to the button and enable it with the function but doesn't work. Also tried to add a second condition .prop('enabled', strength >= 1) but doesn't work too.

Comment: Finally have it working. I don't know if it's the cleanest way... I've added "disabled" to the button by defaut. Then, I've used ```.prop('enabled', strength >= 1)```
 ```.prop('disabled', strength <= 1)```. Maybe something to improve or it's ok?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd do, but I think you only need one, the `disabled` set, right?

Comment: The problem if that I don't add the second condition is that the button is activated by default until something is entered in the input field. Then the function works perfectly.